# Storage::exists tells me the file exists but I can't delete it with Storage::delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-storage

I'm trying to delete a file inside a folder with:

```
Storage::delete(strtolower($fileGroup->name) . '/' . $file->filename);
```

But it returns false and when I check the file it's still there. When I see if the same file exists with:

```
Storage::exists(strtolower($fileGroup->name) . '/' . $file->filename));
```

It returns true.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? I'm using local storage with all the default settings.

Comment: Does the user have enough permission for deleting? Kindly refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137601/minimum-file-permissions-to-delete-a-file for more information

Comment: Yes www-data has all the permissions for deleting.

Comment: if you do dd(strtolower($fileGroup->name) . '/' . $file->filename); does it return the correct file path?

Comment: Yeah it does return the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. When uploading the file, `Storage::put` created a folder with the filename instead of a file. So it failed when I tried to delete it.

```
Storage::put($fileGroup->name . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName() , file_get_contents($file));
```